# how to fix " Uncaught TypeError: b.inst.processing is not a function " error in laravel yajra datatable?

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables, yajra-datatable

when the download button for CSV, PDF etc is clicked it doesn't work only print button works, the other button gives the following error 
" Uncaught TypeError: b.inst.processing is not a function ".

here is some part of my code

```
$(function() {
            var table = $('#users').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('jobapps') !!}',
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                "scrollX": true,
                buttons:[
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [ 10, 50, 100, 500],
                "iTotalRecords":"6",
                "iTotalDisplayRecords":"6"
```

Error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.inst.processing is not a function
    at r.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:36)
    at r.each (datatables.min.js:150)
    at r.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:36)
    at r.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:155)
    at r.processing (datatables.min.js:154)
    at r.action (buttons.html5.min.js:25)
    at q (datatables.min.js:233)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:233)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: I got the same error, how did you fix it?